# Importing variables from php to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I used this:

```
$sqlImport = "INSERT INTO " . $fileName . "(id, asin, amount, salesRank)
    VALUES($id, $asin, $amount, $salesRank)";
```

but, It doesn't return anything. it returns this error:

```
INSERT INTO correctscan(id, asin, amount, salesRank) VALUES(733966071394, B0088YRCGK, 0.00, 23202)
Unknown column 'B0088YRCGK' in 'field list'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error because i am very new to MySQL. If someone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `$asin`, since it's a string.

```
$sqlImport = "INSERT INTO " . $fileName . "(id, asin, amount, salesRank)
    VALUES($id, '$asin', $amount, $salesRank)";
```

But it would be better to learn how to use prepared queries with parameters. Here's a PDO example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $fileName (id, asin, amount, salesRank) VALUES (:id, :asin, :amount, :salesrank)";
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':asin', $asin);
$stmt->bindParam(':amount', $amount);
$stmt->bindParam(':salesrank', $salesRank);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: my only problem with this is the fact that i am so new to sql that I still have no idea what is going on. Would I have to change anything at the top of the php page. For example the connection?

Comment: Since $amount looks something like this `10.99` how would i go about this since there is a . between?

Comment: Yes, you need to learn how to use PDO to make the connection, and change all your code to use those functions. If you're using the mysql extension, it's obsolete and you should stop immediately.

Comment: @Robert There's no problem with that. MySQL understands decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sqlImport = "INSERT INTO " . $fileName . "(id, asin, amount, salesRank)
    VALUES('$id', '$asin', '$amount', '$salesRank')";
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around the numbers, just the string.